# Prevent Celery from rerunning task when broker is lost and reconnected

Tags: flask, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I need help resolving an issue in our production environment.

Our setup:

- flask application run by Cherrypy
- Celery to handle background tasks
- RabbitMQ as message broker (tried redis as well)
- MySQL for Database

The issue:

Once Celery is processing a task and it runs for a period superior to the heartbeat interval with the broker, the broker closes the connection. Once the task is finished processing in Celery and the broker is down it simply relaunches the task.

Tasks are not idempotent, they should be run once and only once even with failure. I am not finding a way to prevent this behavior, I have tried all combinations of Celery settings.

Below my Celery config:

```
CELERY = {'broker_url': 'amqp://**:******@127.0.0.1:5672/rdcovhost',
          'result_backend': 'rpc://**:******@127.0.0.1:5672/rdcovhost',
          'broker_pool_limit': 100, 'broker_connection_timeout': 6000,
          'worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss': True, 'broker_heartbeat': 10,
          'broker_transport_options': {'visibility_timeout': 3600}, 'task_ignore_result': True, 
          'task_publish_retry': False, 'task_acks_late': False}
```

Notes:

- Increasing the heartbeat to a very high value of course is part of the solution but is not a real solution as we want to accommodate real broker intermittent connection
- modifying the task in question to be idempotent is a solution as well but could take significant time to achieve, there is surely a simple fix for the behavior of Celery
- if the Celery worker itself crashes the task is not repeated
- if the broker is down for a long time then comes up the task is repeated

Answer (score 0):

for those who might stumble upon this issue, here's what I did a a workaround (not a definitive solution but deemed acceptable for production):

- I noticed in the debug logs that the task when requeued has an extra flag called 'redelivered' and the value is 'True'
- so in my running tasks I evaluated this flag and if true raising an exception to drop the task altogether, voila !

code to do so:

```
if self.request.delivery_info.get('redelivered'):
        raise Reject('Task is being redelivered')
```